# Appengine getRemainingMillis return 10 minutes for cron activated servlet

Tags: google-app-engine

I have AppEngine Java application which use cron to activate a servlet.
Because I'm doing very short operation I do it inside a loop every few seconds.

I want to know how much time I have left to finish the work before I get the deadline exception so I use getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis() but for some reason it return 10 minutes instead of 1 minute.

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The [cron docs page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) clearly states that requests invoked by cron can run for 10 minutes.

Comment: I get deadline exception after a minute. I'll check again, thanks.